# xampp htdocs permission problem OSX

Tags: macos, xampp

I just installed XAMPP on OSX. I can't add folder on the htdocs via Finder. I can add a folder via the terminal using **sudo mkdir *foldername***. However I want to add folder by not using the **sudo** command.

I execute **ls -ld htdocs** and got this output:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 root  admin  238 Sep 13 14:11 .htdocs
```

How do I add ***myaccount*** so that I can create folder without having to use **sudo**? I'm really confused on the use of chown or chmod.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htdocs` directory belongs to root, which means, as a simple user, you can't modify anything in without using **sudo**.
Try changing the ownership of that folder, or change permissions on it : `chmod 757 .htdocs`.( `rwx r-x rwx` ).

After that you might be able to create a directory in it, either from the command line, or via the Finder.

Comment: 757 does not really make sense: others can write but group members not? 755 seems more appropriate, perhaps 777 if the server needs write permission.

Comment: @jackrabbit - probably, don't really know which group **myaccount** belongs to.

Comment: thanks for the reply, upon changing the permission as you suggested, I still can't create a directory via Terminal and Finder without having to use **sudo**, btw the htdocs has a symbolic link to -> xamppfiles->htdocs

Comment: @Dee - this means you're probably a member of the `admin` group, try 777 instead of 757...

Comment: @Vincent, hmm I run `groups` and I don't see myaccount enlisted in admin group.

Comment: @Dee - what else ? with all rights given to anyone on that folder, you should at least be able to create a directory in.

Comment: @Vincent `lrwxr-xr-x  1 myaccount  admin  17 Feb 28  2010 htdocs -> xamppfiles/htdocs` here is the result of `ls -ld htdocs` after I execute **sudo chmod 757 htdocs**

Comment: You are changing the permissions of the symlink rather than those of the actual directory. What are the permissions on xamppfiles/htdocs?